# Таблица в android

Tags: android, android-layout

Здравствуйте. я создаю динамическую таблицу. Первая строка не динамическая

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#DEDEDE" >
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#DEDEDE" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/DarkGray" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="Аватар"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="Выезд"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="Откуда"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="Куда"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="М/Ц"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Вторая и следующие строки динамические:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#DEDEDE" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageStatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textVuezd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOtkuda"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textKuda"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSeatsPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

</TableRow>
```

Я запускаю эту таблицу как dialog. В итоге получается вот такая картина:
http://www.autostarkiev.com.ua/gg.png

Из-за шрифта, другая часть таблицы не помещается на экране и таблица сама почему имеет отступы от края экрана.

Как сделать так, чтоб текст автоматически переносился на следующую строку, чтоб вся таблица помещалась?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674578/multiline-textview-in-android

Comment: ну тут задается статическая длина одной строки, а как сделать чтоб автоматом? или так нельзя?

Comment: не знаю даже... 
нужно пробегать по твоем строкам и добавлять "\n" для переноса.
другого варианта я не знаю)

Comment: Подозреваю, что переноса нет из-за того, что TextView находится внутри TableRow, потому что обыкновенный TextView нормально переносит строки

Comment: Попробуйте во всех TextView в Row поставить android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: получается кривая таблица по высоте

Comment: Но перенос то работает?

Answer (score 1):

Мне, вобщем, подсказали на стаке, что нужно сделать так

```
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
```

Это сработало и перенос работает, но шапка таблицы кривая.